# how to to catch the UINavigationBar back button pressed event

Tags: iphone

How to to catch the UINavigationBar back button pressed event?
I hope to do something before it navigate/go back to the previous viewcontroller.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `UINavigationBar.delegate` property and implement either `navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` or `navigationBar:didPopItem:` methods of the `UINavigationBarDelegate` protocol.